# Problem loading application when concrete JPA entity classes are in different package than their generic superclass

Tags: java, jpa, generics, spring-data-jpa

Recently I was restructuring and refactoring my code and one of the tasks was to categorize classes into logical groups/packages. Since I'm using a lot of inheritance/subclassing along with generics, I mostly left parent classes where they were and moved their subclasses to separate subpackages.

Below is the example of the directory (as well package) hierarchy that shows how I've done that task:

```
Pet-Registration/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow
├── controller
│   ├── PetOwnerController.java
│   ├── dog
│   │   └── DogOwnerController.java
│   └── cat
│       └── CatOwnerController.java
├── dbmodel
│   ├── Pet.java
│   ├── PetOwner.java
│   ├── dog
│   │   ├── Dog.java
│   │   └── DogOwner.java
│   └── cat
│       ├── Cat.java
│       └── CatOwner.java
├── repository
│   ├── PetOwnerRepository.java
│   ├── dog
│   │   └── DogOwnerRepository.java
│   └── cat
│       └── CatOwnerRepository.java
└── service
    ├── PetOwnerService.java
    ├── dog
    │   └── DogOwnerService.java
    └── cat
        └── CatOwnerService.java
```

Before doing the refinement the directory hierarchy was almost the same, except I didn't have packages like 'dog' and 'cat' from shown example.

When I tried to run my Spring Boot application, it got crashed in a few moments due the following unhandled exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property com.stackoverflow.dbmodel.PetOwner.pets has an unbound type and no explicit target entity. Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit target attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=) or use an explicit @Type

When I reverted changes of moving files within 'dbmodel' directory/package, the application was then able to work properly.

Because of that behavior, I came to conclusion that Spring is probably looking for concrete classes of abstract entity class (class with @Entity annotation) only in the package where that class resides.

**The question is**: Is my conclusion right and if so, is there any workaround to preserve above hierarchy without making the application unable to work?

Below I provide the class definitions of entity classes and some of their subclasses to make this problem easier to reproduce:

PetOwner.java

```java
@Entity
public abstract class PetOwner<PET extends Pet<?>> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PET> pets;
}
```

DogOwner.java

```java
@Entity
public class DogOwner extends PetOwner<Dog> {
}
```

Pet.java

```java
@Entity
public abstract class Pet<OWNER extends PetOwner<?>> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private OWNER owner;
}
```

Dog.java

```java
@Entity
public class Dog extends Pet<DogOwner> {
}
```

Comment: And your code really worked before? Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676914/bidirectional-many-to-one-with-subclasses-and-generics

Comment: @Jens Because these are the generic types not the classes

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes, the code works fine when subclasses are put into the same package where their superclass is.

Comment: That doesn't makes sense. I will try to reproduce your problem

Comment: But the link you provided was indeed useful! Explicitly specifying targetEnity property to the ManyToOne and OneToMany annotations actually helped me to make the application work when the subclasses are located in the different packages.
Please, post the answer, so I can accept it. If you are capable and willing to provide any additional information for such a behavior, please do so

Comment: I could reproduce your problem and indeed setting the targetEntity works. I add this as the answer. Why it works without targetEntity when the classes are in the same package I have no idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the targetEntity attribute on the relationships in the abstract classes:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Pet<OWNER extends PetOwner<?>> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = PetOwner.class)
    private OWNER owner;
}

@Entity
public abstract class PetOwner<PET extends Pet<?>> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Pet.class)
    private List<PET> pets;
}
```